# Magento image upload feature adds script with the IMG tag

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I have a freshly installed Magento with a theme that is working fine in my local environment. But since my last deployment to staging everytime I use the "Insert Image..." button in any CMS page or block, the images get pasted with a HUGE script that I have no idea what it does or where it came from.

My local is still working fine, no signs of that behavior. Could it be some sort of malware in my server? any ideas?

Here is a sample of the script that I'm getting:

```
    <head/><script pagespeed_no_defer="" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
(function(){var g=this,h=function(b,d){var a=b.split("."),c=g;a[0]in c||!c.execScript||c.execScript("var "+a[0]);for(var e;a.length&&(e=a.shift());)a.length||void 0===d?c[e]?c=c[e]:c=c[e]={}:c[e]=d};var l=function(b){var d=b.length;if(0<d){for(var a=Array(d),c=0;c<d;c++)a[c]=b[c];return a}return[]};var m=function(b){var d=window;if(d.addEventListener)d.addEventListener("load",b,!1);else if(d.attachEvent)d.attachEvent("onload",b);else{var a=d.onload;d.onload=function(){b.call(this);a&&a.call(this)}}};var n,p=function(b,d,a,c,e){this.f=b;this.h=d;this.i=a;this.c=e;this.e={height:window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight,width:window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth};this.g=c;this.b={};this.a=[];this.d={}},q=function(b,d){var a,c,e=d.getAttribute("pagespeed_url_hash");if(a=e&&!(e in b.d))if(0>=d.offsetWidth&&0>=d.offsetHeight)a=!1;else{c=d.getBoundingClientRect();var f=document.body;a=c.top+("pageYOffset"in window?window.pageYOffset:(document.documentElement||f.parentNode||f).scrollTop);c=c.left+("pageXOffset"in window?window.pageXOffset:(document.documentElement||f.parentNode||f).scrollLeft);f=a.toString()+","+c;b.b.hasOwnProperty(f)?a=!1:(b.b[f]=!0,a=a<=b.e.height&&c<=b.e.width)}a&&(b.a.push(e),b.d[e]=!0)};p.prototype.checkImageForCriticality=function(b){b.getBoundingClientRect&&q(this,b)};h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality",function(b){n.checkImageForCriticality(b)});h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkCriticalImages",function(){r(n)});var r=function(b){b.b={};for(var d=["IMG","INPUT"],a=[],c=0;c<d.length;++c)a=a.concat(l(document.getElementsByTagName(d[c])));if(0!=a.length&&a[0].getBoundingClientRect){for(c=0;d=a[c];++c)q(b,d);a="oh="+b.i;b.c&&(a+="&n="+b.c);if(d=0!=b.a.length)for(a+="&ci="+encodeURIComponent(b.a[0]),c=1;c<b.a.length;++c){var e=","+encodeURIComponent(b.a[c]);131072>=a.length+e.length&&(a+=e)}b.g&&(e="&rd="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(s())),131072>=a.length+e.length&&(a+=e),d=!0);t=a;if(d){c=b.f;b=b.h;var f;if(window.XMLHttpRequest)f=new XMLHttpRequest;else if(window.ActiveXObject)try{f=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(k){try{f=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(u){}}f&&(f.open("POST",c+(-1==c.indexOf("?")?"?":"&")+"url="+encodeURIComponent(b)),f.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),f.send(a))}}},s=function(){var b={},d=document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");if(0==d.length)return{};var a=d[0];if(!("naturalWidth"in a&&"naturalHeight"in a))return{};for(var c=0;a=d[c];++c){var e=a.getAttribute("pagespeed_url_hash");e&&(!(e in b)&&0<a.width&&0<a.height&&0<a.naturalWidth&&0<a.naturalHeight||e in b&&a.width>=b[e].k&&a.height>=b[e].j)&&(b[e]={rw:a.width,rh:a.height,ow:a.naturalWidth,oh:a.naturalHeight})}return b},t="";h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.getBeaconData",function(){return t});h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.Run",function(b,d,a,c,e,f){var k=new p(b,d,a,e,f);n=k;c&&m(function(){window.setTimeout(function(){r(k)},0)})});})();pagespeed.CriticalImages.Run('/mod_pagespeed_beacon','http://misregalitos.com.uy/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/onInsert/key/7ecc593da1f3e83b11bd56a8a672bc4e/?isAjax=true','Ez0F1MDYS1',true,false,'-gTeG_ldX9c');
//]]></script><img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg misregalitos blanco-swatch.png"}}" alt="" pagespeed_url_hash="1171663282" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have recently installed Google's ***mod_pagespeed*** on your staging environment. Failing that, perhaps your host has installed it on your behalf.

**mod_pagespeed** is a (mostly) ***frontend performance optimization tool built*** by Google to help you optimize and improve your page load, with features such as load critical ***css, lazy load images, defer unnecessary JavaScript,*** etc.

For more information, I suggest you read about the **Defer JavaScript** feature in `mod_pagespeed` [here:](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/DeferJavaScript)

Assuming your staging environment runs on Apache, you will need to edit `.htaccess` to enable or disable the various features of `mod_pagespeed`. More on that here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/install.

To disable `mod_pagespeed altogether`, you will need to edit either *pagespeed.conf* (Apache) or *nginx.conf* (Nginx). See the helpfile above for assistance on that.

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally got pagespeed disabled and it fixed my issue! Thanks!

Comment: Happy it solved your issue. Kindly select this as the answer and if the answer was high quality,  feel free to give it an upvote.